# How do I call Android IcePick saveInstanceState from onPause()?

Tags: android, onpause, onsaveinstancestate

I use `IcePick` to save my instance state. 
How do I save the instance state at `onPause()`, instead of at `onSaveInstanceState()` ?

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Icepick.saveInstanceState(this, outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't bother with it, `onSaveInstanceState()` is one of the last methods that is guaranteed to be called by `Android` OS. By sticking to `onSaveInstanceState()` you follow the official `Activity` lifecycle.

Comment: My problem is, the back-button does not call onSaveInstanceState(). And I really do want to save the state when the user clicks the back button.

Comment: Then override `onBackPressed` to call out to save a `Bundle` or a `SharedPreferences` for that Activity

Answer (score 0):

another way to use share preference on  on pause and get value from on resume from share preference it will work